# How to optimize

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

A function $f$ has to be minimized,

$$f=  \sum_i^k \beta_i e^{\alpha_i n_i}$$

where $\alpha_i$'s and $\beta_i$'s are known. How can I find optimal values of $n_i$'s that minimises $f$, given the constraint $\sum_i^k {n_i} \leq N$.

---

Edit:

$n_i \geq 0$ and $\alpha_i$ are negative $\beta_i$ are positive.

Sorry for the confusion. I couldn't apply Lagrangian due to large number of constraints making it unsolvable. Is there some other way to do or program that could help me.

Comment: Do we know whether or not the $\alpha_i$, $\beta_i$ are positive?  Also, are the $n_i$ necessarily integers?

Comment: @B.Mehta $\beta_i$ are negative while $\alpha_i$ can be either positive or negative.

Comment: Have you tried Lagrangian's multipliers?

Comment: @B.Mehta I am doing the log-likelihood with the Lagrangian but I am not sure if it is the right way.

Comment: If you're ok with an approximation, I think there is a trick used in ML where you take the log (max f = max log(f)), and make an approximation by switching the log and the sum. (So max sum log f $\geq$ max log sum f.) (I think...) Then you can treat it more or less like an LP. (Google "optimizing log sum exp" for more on the topic)

Comment: @YiningWang. I tried using the Lagrangian and get stuck with following equation,

$$\sum_i^k \frac{1}{\alpha_i} \log{ \frac{\alpha_i \beta_i} {\lambda}  } = N$$

Comment: @B.Mehta; @ YiningWang, @whyyes. I think I solved it. Thanks so much for the help. I can get $\lambda$. Sorry for the pain. I was doing a stupid mistake.